# Can I install an AMD Turion X2 64 RM-70 on a Toshiba Satellite L505D-SP6983R?

Tags: laptop, cpu

The original processor was an AMD Turion X2 64 RM-74 (dead)

The board is named V000185220 Rev 1.10

This board accepts S1G2 processors, and should accept the RM-70. But I am not so confident when dealing with laptop Hardware. The RM-70 isn't listed as compatible in any posted list I could find.